# How to mark an imported Cocoapod framework deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, deprecated

In one of our frameworks we're using the SwiftObserver pod. Our framework is used in several other frameworks of our app.

After raising the development target to iOS 13.0 I'd like to mark all usage of the SwiftObserver methods as deprecated to gradually change our codebase to use Combine's observers.

I was thinking of forking SwiftObserver or linking a local copy of the pod from now on. However parts of the app that still use SwiftObserver should be able to continue updating it using `pod update` as long as not all code has been changed to use Combine.

Is there a simpler way, maybe in the podfile, or with some sort of overwrite, to mark the usage of that pod deprecated without breaking any of its funktionality?

Please let me know if you have further questions or if there are any code samples I can provide.

Comment: There's no such thing as a deprecated library. Parts of the library can be marked as deprecate, but it makes little sense to mark the whole library as deprecate, considering that the code in the library evolves over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to using swiftlint proposed by @SoumyaMahunt, could be to setup your own private repo.

Here's how you might be able to achieve what you want:

1. Create a private spec repo to be used to resolve the CocoaPod dependencies.
2. Create a podspec for [SwiftObserver](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/8/0/a/SwiftObserver/6.3.0/SwiftObserver.podspec.json) and set it to deprecated -> `s.deprecated = true`
3. Add the private spec repo above `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`, this is important to force CocoaPods to resolve against your private repo before searching in the global default repo.

Pros

- You can use this private spec repo for other private pods
- You can deprecate other pods without having to *hack* in your project.

Cons

- Can be tideous to manually make sure the third-party pods are updated to the latest versions (you'll have to manually add new podspecs for the updated version).

###### Helpful links:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deprecated

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however when marking the new private pod deprecated only `pod update` gives a deprecation warning. Is there a way to mark any use of the methods from that pod as deprecated? Without marking the methods individually?

Comment: Did you try to to run `pod install` on a fresh CocoaPod configuration without the `Podfile.lock` created yet?

Comment: Yes, I ran `pod deintegrate`, `pod clean`, `pod cache clean --all`, `pod install` and cleaned the build folder before building. I still don't get any deprecation warnings inside of Xcode. Maybe there is a setting I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Make sure to also remove the `Podfile.lock` before attempting to run `pod install` after `pod deintegrate`.

Comment: Yes I did that, also `pod clean` is doing that as well. It seems as if I'm missing some other setting that prevents Xcode from showing those warnings. I'll try out more.

Comment: I ended up using your solution with some extra steps. I basically marked all classes I was using as deprecated. I don't know why it doesn't work to just mark the whole pod as deprecated or if it's even possible. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [swiftlint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint), you can add custom rule to produce warning with a message indicating deprecation. You can also adjust severity of these warning to cause compilation error as well.

For producing warning with `SwiftObserver` pod create the following custom rule in swift lint [config file (`.swiftlint.yml`)](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#configuration):

```
custom_rules:
  pod_deprecation:
    name: "Deprecated POD use"
    regex: "(SwiftObserver)"
    match_kinds:
      - identifier
    message: "Use of deprecated pods"
```

This rule will cause warning with the message provided in the `message` parameter for all the files that import `SwiftObserver`:

[image: sample warning]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you update your answer with a code example on how to implement that custom rule for a pod?

Comment: @MarcoBoerner added sample config you need to add to swift config file, more advanced options are described in the project page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code update. It works pretty well for marking the import as deprecated. Still I went with Laffens solution with some changes in order to mark every used class deprecated. None of it is ideal and I'd preferred a much smoother solution. But thanks again for the effort! : )